# How does ForeignKey work in this Django example?

Tags: django-models, django-views

I am having trouble understanding how to use ForeignKey and what exactly it does.  Does it link two tables?  Or does it link specific columns between each table?  Here is a very basic example:

```
class Seller(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    email = models.CharField()
    zipcode = models.CharField()

class ItemsForSale(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField()
    description = models.CharField()
    zipcode = models.ForeignKey(Seller)
```

What I'm trying to do is when someone fills out a form to sell an item, I want the zipcode for that item to be automatically set as the sellers zipcode (so the end user won't even have to fill out a zipcode in the form).

Why is it ForeignKey(Seller) instead of ForeignKey(Seller.zipcode)?  I guess I don't understand am I linking the entire 'Seller' table?  Or just the zipcode column?

Since I don't understand how ForeignKey works, I don't know how to write a view method that sets the zipcode for ItemsForSale. so I really think the key to helping me understand all this would be to see a proper view method that sets the ItemForSale's zipcode to the Sellers zipcode.

Answer (score 0):

In Django a `ForeignKey` is a relationship between Objects.

In a database a `ForeignKey` is a field (column) in a table that links to a row of another table.

Visit the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) and [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) for more information about `ForeignKeys`.

**Now to your Django example:**

Every single Item (ItemsForSale) has a Seller. (Note: Model names should always be singular.)

So we add a `ForeignKey` in your `ItemsForSale`-model that relates to the item's seller:

```
class ItemsForSale(models.Model):
    ...
    seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller)
```

Now you can access the item's seller (and of course all of his attributes (including his zipcode) this way:

```
ItemsForSale.get(item='Foo').seller.zipcode
```

Comment: Thank you, this makes sense, but under Class ItemsForSale, should I also put zipcode=models.ForeignKey(Seller) ?

Comment: No, because `seller = models.ForeignKey(Seller)` already connects your item with its seller. As I said above, you can access the seller's zipcode via the item's relationship to its seller. `zipcode=models.ForeignKey(Seller)` does not really make sense, because it would create another relationship between item and seller, but the relationship to the item's seller would be called 'zipcode' (and not seller), that means you would have to access a zipcode like this: `item.zipcode.zipcode` instead of `item.seller.zipcode`.

Comment: I understand.  So I can do zipcode = models.Charfield(max_length=8) inside class ItemForSale.

Comment: Are the items' zipcodes always the same as the related sellers' zipcodes? If yes, then you don't need an extra `zipcode`-attribute in `ItemForSale`. If the item's and seller's zipcodes are different, then you should add a `zipcode`-attribute in `ItemForSale`.

Comment: Okay that makes sense (they are always the same).  Thank you!